# Export a local git

Tags: git, svn, tortoisegit

I am working on windows, with tortoise git. I am having a problem where GIT does not work on my computer any more (I can't do any git command). I want to quickly switch to svn so I can keep working.

Is there a way to clean up my entire project folder so that all git files are gone, and I can copy all the files in a clean svn repo ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should rather fix git instead of switching to svn. Try installing `msysgit` and using the command-line git utilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the **.git** directory or even better copy all the other files except the .git directory in the svn working copy.

Comment: @Jan subversion 1.7 is also awesome then